# Is there a complete list of unusual skills?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills

The SRD lists the core skills, as well as the skills added by *Expanded Psionics Handbook* (Autohypnosis, Knowledge (psionics), Psicraft, Use Psionic Device). There is also, in the SRD but hidden, [the Control Shape skill used by lycanthropes](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/lycanthrope.htm#lycanthropyAsAnAffliction).

But some supplements add new skills. The Iaijutsu Focus skill from *Oriental Adventures* is fairly well-known. *Tome of Battle*’s Martial Lore is another Spellcraft analogue, and *Tome of Magic*’s Truenaming is the skill that fuels the worst class in the game. And a friend just came across the bizarre Handle Monstrous Spider skill from *Dungeon* vol. 84, which I’d never heard of before.

Since the factotum class gains all skills as class skills, unusual skills can sometimes be relevant to one. Does anyone know of a *really* thorough listing of skills, including *Dragon* and *Dungeon* magazines and all Wizards of the Coast supplements for 3.0e and 3.5e? Primarily interested in totally-new skills, rather than new Craft, Knowledge, Perform, or Profession skills (though when they get special rules, as with Craft (poisonmaking), or most Knowledge skills, that’s more interesting).

Comment: "Drow from the Demonweb have the option to take a skill called Handle Monstrous Spider that functions just like Handle Animal but works on Abyssal monstrous spiders (and only on Abyssal spiders…)" (*Dungeon* #84 29). Seriously, that's absurd—like Sartre in tutu absurd. But, hey, expert, factotum, and savant, you each put 1 rank in that, right?

Comment: Crystalkeep had a list of skills, however it was not complete and it also included actions, including oddball uses of skills.

Comment: @nijineko Mentioned in my answer. Only covers core skills, though it does cover non-core uses.

Comment: (As an aside, I really did start to compile such a list, but I grew weary of the task's length and the detail work it required. Once you *start* looking, it becomes overwhelming. Really, the prestige class [conventioneer](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/cc/20010420a) alone adds, like, 20 skills to the game—go ahead, Mr. Factotum, and spend skill points on the skills Juggle Workload, Not Work, and Solve Puzzle!)

Answer (score 10):

I have not been able to find such a list yet. Here’s various partial lists I was able to dredge up:

- For completion’s sake, there are the skills mentioned in the question: Control Shape (*Monster Manual*), Iaijutsu Focus (*Oriental Adventures*), Handle Monstrous Spider (*Dungeon* vol. 84), Martial Lore (*Tome of Battle*), and Truenaming (*Tome of Magic*).
- We have [an existing question on a list of all additional skill uses](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79854/4563), which at present does not seem to exist, but new skills rather than new usages of old skills are considerably less common and therefore maybe more plausible. But so far I haven’t found it.
- @Forrestfire, who found Handle Monstrous Spiders in the first place, wrote up a [list of neat *Dungeon* content](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e5s2QwozL_7RALrxM0NLzghZrUhd4Jt19-7CChP0JXA/edit#gid=0), which also mentions Knowledge (Computer Literacy) and Ride (Ground Vehicles) from *Dungeon* vol. 83.
- The Crystal Keep index only handles core skills (but doesn’t miss Control Shape, which is nice).
- [This thread](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?190499-3-5-Profession-Skills) compiles a large number of explicitly-mentioned Profession skills. No idea how comprehensive it is—and I kind of don’t care.
- [Another thread](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?416707-Creating-a-Condensed-List-of-Craft-Skills) endeavors to cover Craft skills. Again, unsure how comprehensive it is, and not overly worried about it.
- And [here is a thread entitled “Is there an official exhaustive Skill list out there?”](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?237477-Is-there-an-official-exhaustive-Skill-list-out-there), and though the opening post actually asks about Craft skills, posters seem to favor answering the title question and mention Handle Humanoid ([“Fabulous Cats” April Fools’ Web Enhancement](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/fools/20030401c)), Perform (Weapon Drill) (*Complete Warrior*), and Lucid Dreaming (*Manual of the Planes*), which I’d forgotten about.